# parse hierarchic xml

Tags: c#, xml

I want to know how I can parse this XML:

```
<MenuItems>
  <MenuItem Id="2" Name="Country">
    <MenuItem Id="2272" Name="Europe">
      <MenuItem Id="888" Name="Austria"/>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Id="2572" Name="Asia">
  <MenuItem Id="2572" Name="Japan"/>
    </MenuItem>
      </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem Id="3" Name="Car">
    <MenuItem Id="231" Name="Diesel">
      <MenuItem Id="387" Name="Toyota">
    <MenuItem Id="387" Name="Avensis"/>
      </MenuItem>
    </MenuItem>
  </MenuItem>
</MenuItems>
```

and write the following out to the console:

> Country 
>   -Europe
>   --Austria
>   -Asia
>   --Japan
>   Car
>   -Diesel
>   --Toyota
>   ---Avensis

I don't know in advance the depth of the child in the hierarchy.

**My code:**

```
XElement doc = XElement.Parse(DataXml);
XElement MenuNode = doc.XPathSelectElement("/MenuItem");
var segmentNodes = MenuNode.XPathSelectElements("/");

foreach (XElement segmentNode in segmentNodes)
{
  var segmentAlignment = (string)segmentNode.Attribute("Name");
  Console.Writeline(segmentAlignment);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

. . . 

void PrintMenu(XElement menuElement, string prefix)
{
  string newPrefix = prefix + "-";
  foreach (XElement subMenuElement in menuElement.XPathSelectElements("MenuItem")) {
    Console.WriteLine(prefix+(string)subMenuElement.Attribute("Name"));
    PrintMenu(subMenuElement, newPrefix);
  }
}

. . . 

XElement doc = XElement.Parse(DataXml); 
PrintMenu(doc, String.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really two questions:

1. [How to parse XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220867/how-to-deal-with-xml-in-c-sharp)
2. [How to traverse a recursive list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10878268/recursive-reading-of-listobject)

Both are trivial and sufficiently well-explained elsewhere.